pymqi and XA transactions?
I want to be able to use a single coordinated transaction (two phase commit) that takes messages from MQ and manipulates a Db2 database using part of the contents of the MQ-message, and to post another MQ message, all in a single distributed transaction (using XA protocol) , using an external transaction-manager (for example using IBM txseries or equivalent as the XA transaction-manager).
I'm able to use XA transactions involving two distributed Db2 databases via a customized ibm_db module for python but I seek to  involve MQ using an external transaction manager so that a single transaction can span these product.
Does pymqi link with the XA library supplied with IBM MQ , and if so , is pymqi able to participate in XA transactions? Are there any examples and testcases or resources for using XA with pymqi ?

From an MQ perspective, there should be nothing needed for a pymqi application to work in XA mode with an external coordinator. It's the coordinator that has to access the XA switch interface in the C libraries and thereby control the flow.
All your app needs to do is ensure that it's using MQG/PMO_SYNCPOINT and those messages will be automatically included in the transaction. Python would be no different than the C applications in this respect.
But obviously, your app also needs to call the TM's verbs to start and end transactions. That's outside the pymqi scope, so you'd have to make sure you're also using whatever python package gives you access to them.
